# Algorithm for unique KEY generation

Tags: c

i need to generate unique values by using ipv4 and ipv6 addresses i.e if i input 192.37.4.60; a unique key should be generated and when i enter 192.60.4.37 a another key should be generated. How can i do this can any one help me out and i can also input ipv6 address also how to generate unique values to each input. can any one propse any algorithm or any present algorithm

Comment: Why don't you use IP addresses themselves for keys?

Comment: How will the key be used. Since it might influence the choice of algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the IP into its numerical (decimal) representation:

10.0.0.1 -> 00001010 00000000 00000000 00000001 -> 167772161

This is how a lot of IP addresses are stored internally. It's nice because it only requires 32 bits of storage. You can do this for IPv6 too, but it's going to require something bigger than a uint32.

Comment: what to do when i  have a ipv6 address

Comment: @hopeless: See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa921042.aspx). The same logic applies, but it's slightly more difficult because IPv6 can have missing digits (leading zeros can be removed), so you need to account for that.

Comment: and once you've converted your IPv6 address to binary (per the article), that 128-bit number can then be used like any other number. You can use it as a key if you want.

Answer (score 1):

The IPs are pretty unique :) Especially IPv6 addresses. 
Also, you can always use a hash algorithm (e.g. MD5, SHA1 etc.) to create a "key". It will be unique, as long as the input data is also unique :)

Comment: i tried out MD5 algo but the o/p is 128 bits, i did some thing like this                                           [root@INFBA01415 ~]# vi simple.txt                   [root@INFBA01415 ~]# md5sum simple.txt d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e simple.txt                                                          when i tried just to print this data it gives out a error

Comment: @static_rtti: glad you added that disclaimer. @BasicWolf: regardless, using a cryptographic hash 128 to 160 bits wide (as is the case for MD5 and SHA1 respectively) is way overkill for hashing 32 bit IPv4 addresses, and not much more sensible 128 bit IPv6 addresses. There is probably little if any appreciable gain in the degree of uniqueness (compared to just using the addresses) for a quite considerable processing penalty.

Answer (score 0):

Output the input IP address: voilà, requirements met!

(If my solution doesn't work for you, it means you need to add more details to your question)

Comment: wht in case i enter a ipv6 address i get do that as it wll go out of range and i dont want such big numbers also

Comment: @hopeless coder: If you want a unique key for any possible IPv6 address, then you must put up with the key being a 128 bit number, because that's simply how many unique IPv6 addresses there are.  Alternatively, you could simply create a table of keys to IP addresses, assigning keys sequentially as you see a new IP address.

Comment: @hopeless coder: you didn't even specify you wanted *numbers* in your question. If you don't explain what you want to achive, it's impossible to help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of solution possible depending of what are the needs of your problem.

1. You *could* use the IP address themselves, but keep in mind that an IP address can be spoofed.
2. If you intend to use this key amongst multiple peers in order to secure a communication channel, then you might want to take a look towards the [symmetric-key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm) or [public-key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) algorithms
3. If you *only* want to use them for some static data you can use either of these : [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5), [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) and [SHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm)*.

You might want to look to use multiple source for your algorithm. Consider using, in combination with the MAC address, any other material-related information that you can obtain from the machine/client on which the application will run

Comment: i tried out MD5 algo but the o/p is 128 bits, i did some thing like this                                           [root@INFBA01415 ~]# vi simple.txt                   [root@INFBA01415 ~]# md5sum simple.txt d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e simple.txt                                                          when i tried just to print this data it gives out a error

Comment: i converted the above hexa value to decimla equivalent ant tried to print that #include<stdio.h> int main() { long int x= 15284527576400310788; printf("%ld\n",x); return 0; } but i get an error test.c:4:14: warning: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned test.c: In function `main': test.c:4: warning: this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90 test.c:4: warning: integer constant is too large for "long" type test.c:4: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion

Comment: @hopless coder : maybe you want to take a look at this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5sum

Answer (score 0):

one possible solution can be to use left shift operator and add. For example if a, b, c and d represent the octets then following code will give you a unique value

```
int a=1;
int b=2;
int c=3;
int d=4;

int value =(a<<24)+(b<<16)+(c<<8)+d;
```

Comment: It's not usually a good idea to invent your own crypto algorithms.

Comment: @Francis: this is how a dotted-decimal IPv4 address is represented, Raza didn't make this up. This is storing the address "1.2.3.4" in 32 bits. However there IS a small bug because of the fact that he's using a signed int. Also a, b, c, and d could potentially be bigger than 255 which would cause problems.

Comment: I'm not saying that this is not how it's represented, I'm saying that it's not a good idea to pull out a crypto algorithm (but now I see that's only the representation, not a crypto algo) on the fly.

Comment: Just because there's bit twiddling doesn't mean it's crypto.

Comment: @Chris thanks for pointing that out... it shows that you know a lot in crypto.

Answer (score 0):

You don't state any required properties of the keys excet that thy should be unique, so the obvious solution is to use the canonicalized IP addresses as keys. You can turn the addresses into numbers the obvious way, but be warned that IPv6 addresses make for huge numbers, so you'll need the BigInt implementation in whatever language you use.

(If you *didn't* actually mean that all 340 undecillion addresses should have unique keys, then of course you should look at normal hash functions instead.)

Answer (score 0):

Another option can be to use the [inet_pton](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2928/index.htm?info/apis/inet_pton.htm) directly.